# difference between Scalable Vector Graphics (SVG) images & jpeg images?

Tags: xml, svg

I just want to know which image loads faster in web browsers, svg or jpeg.?

Comment: There is no way to answer this question in general; it is entirely dependent on the image you are creating, how the SVG is built, how the JPEG is compressed, and what image dimensions you want. It also depends on what you mean by "load": over the wire file size, or decompression/display speed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

JPGs will take longer to download (as they store pixel info) svg's will take slightly longer to render as they only store vector information.

Most people prefer SVG's when they can as it preserves the original intent of the image better, and as a general rule they are a lot smaller, and can be rendered at much higher quality especially when zoomed. The downside is browser compatibility. SVG elements only work natively in HTML with the latest browsers, for older browsers they are still usable but need to be embedded inside other elements.

Comment: Totally depends on the picture and resolution.